# Force "free-shipping" inside a product tag.

Tags: expresso-store

Is there any way to add a template tag or hidden input and force free shipping for all the items that use a template?

The site I'm working on sells some physical products, but also has a "classes" section.

I'd like to simplify the class creation process for my clients. It would also help them avoid errors if they miss the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add the items to discount and check free shipping .

https://exp-resso.com/docs/control_panel_discounts.html

Answer (score 1):

The 'Free Shipping' checkbox on the Publish/Edit screen is obviously the best way to do it on a per-product basis but if you wanted to include an extra failsafe then it could be an option to create a Shipping Method with a 'Free Shipping' rule. You could set the shipping rates to 0 in that rule but bear in mind that this applies *per order* and not *per product*. So if there's a chance that someone could add both a physical product as well as a course/class to their cart in the same checkout then it would cause a problem. You could then loop through the cart contents and if it contains a course/class (identified by category, product ID's, SKU's etc) then automatically set the shipping method to 'Free Shipping' in the templates.